# MonoDevelop 2.4.2 or 2.6b2 Does not render fonts on MacBookPro

Tags: macos, monodevelop

On a clean MacBook I installed all the latest Apple updates and Mono 2.10.2 SDK / MDK
The mono installer did not create a symlink from `/Library/Frameworks/Mono/framework/Mono.framework/Versions/Current` to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2` so I added that.

My path was also not updated so I added a text file called mono to /etc/paths.d
With just this line in it
`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin`

None of the characters in either MonoDevelop 2.42 or 2.6b render correctly. All characters are replaced with a `✋` (rectangle). This suggests to me that I am missing a font or that there is possibly something incorrectly configured on my Mac.

Any advice? Do I need to manually configure anything else for mono / MonoDevelop?

Comment: Everything is set to American English: en-US

Comment: Running `locale` in terminal displays: `LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing, are you installing as a local account, and then running as a network account? We're looking into moving the font collections from the local account into the network account.

If you need it to use it, then can you log in as one of the other accounts?

Will report when a solution is found.

Comment: Installing and running as a local account. Will test again once resolved.